# What is the usage of 有 in 有比丘五下分結盡?

Tags: meaning, usage

Here is the phrase, it is from Buddhist scripture: 有比丘五下分結盡

I know 有 as "to be", "to have", and as often serving as a translation for the Sanskrit *bhāva*.

Is this usage something like "being monks, [etc]"?

Comment: I've learned that 有 at the beginning of a sentence can often be interpreted as "there are" meaning "there is at least one in existence" or "the world has at least one of...".

Answer (score 9):

> 有比丘五下分結盡。

有（些）比丘五下分結（已滅）盡。
有些比丘已滅盡五下分結。
***Some*** bhiksus (Sanskrit: bhikṣu) have completely eliminated five lower-realm bonds.

此處之「下分」是指「欲界」。三界中，欲界處於最下層，低於色界、無色界，故稱之為下分。
下分 here means Realm of Sensuous Desire (Sanskrit: kāma-dhātu). It is the lowest level in the Three Realms, lower than the Realm of Form and the Realm of Formlessness. Thus, it is named 下分(界).

「結」是「繫縛」之義，亦即「煩惱」。此等煩惱繫縛眾生於三界，令吾等無止盡地輪迴，故名之為「結」。
結 (Sanskrit: saṃyojana; bandhana) here means the bond, whose alias is the affliction (Sanskrit: kleśa). The affliction fastens all beings in the Three Realms, and makes us transmigrate endlessly. Therefore, it is named 結.

五下分結 （Sanskrit: pañca-āvara-bhāgīya-saṃyojanāni, five lower-realm bonds）：
貪 (desire)
瞋 (anger; dislike)
身見：執著實我 (real self)
戒取：邪戒 (heretical precept or discipline)
疑 (doubt)

Answer (score 4):

in 雜阿含經　卷二十九, [0209c13]

http://tripitaka.cbeta.org/T02n0099_029

in this scripture "有" is used as "there was / were".

started from:

> 今此眾中諸長老比丘

now (今) the senior monks (諸長老比丘) in the audience (此眾中)

> 有得初禪﹒第二禪﹒第三禪﹒第四禪﹒慈﹒悲﹒喜﹒捨﹒空入處﹒識入處﹒無所有入處﹒非想非非想處具足住
>
> 有比丘三結盡﹒得須陀洹﹒不墮惡趣法﹒決定正向三菩提﹒七有天人往生﹒究竟苦邊
>
> 有比丘三結盡﹒貪﹒恚﹒癡薄﹒得斯陀含
>
> 有比丘五下分結盡﹒得阿那含﹒生般涅槃﹒不復還生此世
>
> 有比丘得無量神通境界﹒天耳﹒他心智﹒宿命智﹒
>   生死智﹒漏盡智
>
> 有比丘修不淨觀﹒斷貪欲﹒修慈心﹒斷瞋恚﹒修無常想﹒斷我慢﹒修安那般那念﹒斷覺想

the buddha (世尊) described that there was / were (有) some monk(s) (比丘) gain various level of achievements

again, i'm not dare translate these buddhism terms, please consult specialised dictionary :)

have fun :)